# what does 'ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query mean '?

Tags: mysql

I was creating some tables in a database through python.Initially it was working but later whenever I use that database and issue commands on its tables I get the error
`ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query` but other databases are working fine. I don't have much in that database so i wanted to drop it , but can't even issue that command(gives same error).

What do I do ?? Also why did this happened did I make somet tables with constraints that could not be possible or something else ??

Comment: Have you reviewed your server's error log?

Comment: @RobinHallabro No How do we do that ?? What can we know from it ??

Comment: Depends on what OS/distro you are using. Look for it inside /var/log/mysql or similiar place to start with. It will most likely tell you why the connection is dropped, unless this is a network related problem.

Comment: @RobinHallabro I looked into it but can't figure what all is wriiten in it , I just want to drop this errorneous db and create it again